# Reverse proxy with single sign-on and backend authentication modules

Tags: authentication, reverse-proxy, single-sign-on

Has anyone got any recommendations for reverse proxy software that provides a single sign-on interface to multiple backend websites via various authentication mechanisms?

e.g.

Login to the frontend proxy (LDAP/AD/whatever). Based on the destination and credentials:

- www.proxy.com/foo issues a POST login to backend website 'A'
- www.proxy.com/bar sets a HTTP Header to allow access to backend website 'B'
- and so on...

It seems like a pretty common scenario for integrating different websites into a portal (e.g. via IFRAME), but I'm really struggling to find anything suitable.

There is a commercial product by Juniper called SSL VPN that does exactly this, but I'm looking for an open source solution, primarily one with custom backend authentication modules.

Thanks.